# Prove that the set $B = \{x \in\mathbb R^n \mid\operatorname{dist}(x,A) > 0\}$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, epsilon-delta

First question here on Math.stackexchange. I am working on a proof and looking for some help/guidance.

The question is as follows:

Let $A \subset\mathbb R^n$ be any nonempty set. Show that the set $B = \{\hat{x} \in\mathbb R^n \mid \operatorname{dist}(\hat{x},A) >
0\}$ is open.

My proof thus far:

1: I start by assuming A is a closed set.

If so is the case, then the closest point to any $\hat{x}$ will be a limit point on A. Since the distance between A and $\hat{x}$ is greater than $0$, can I instantly deduce that in this case B is an open set? (Since B would contain a Ball with a radius $> 0$ for any $\hat{x}$ and by definition be an open set.)

2: Now, assuming A is an open set:

In order to show that B is also an open set, B must contain a ball $C$, centered at $\hat{x}$ with radius $r > 0$ and points $\hat{d}$ around $\hat{x}$ , such that:
$C_{r}(\hat{x}) = \{\hat{d} ∈ \mathbb R^n: 0 < |\hat{d}-\hat{x}|<r,   r>0\}. $

We also know that $\hat{x}$ is of distance $dist(\hat{x},A) >0$ from A and we know that $\hat{x}$ is of some distance from $\hat{d}$, where $\hat{d}$ can be on the straight line between A and $\hat{x}$.

Also, since A is open, its' limit points is not in the open set A and can be said to be of distance $\epsilon, \epsilon > 0$.

If I now say that the distance between $\hat{x}$ and $A$, i.e. $dist(\hat{x},A) = |\hat{d}-\hat{x}| + \epsilon$. Then by setting $|\hat{d}-\hat{x}| = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, we have the distance to be:

$dist(\hat{x},A) = \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \epsilon$.

Since the $dist(\hat{x},A)$ is greater than the distance $|\hat{d}-\hat{x}|$, this should prove that the ball C is in the set B?

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Without reading the details, you're at the very least missing the case where $A$ is neither closed nor open.

Comment: I would just show $f(x)=\operatorname{dist}(x,A)$ is continuous. (Why is that enough?)

Comment: I would consider proving that $B^C$ is closed. $B^C=\{x:d(x,A)=0\}$. This set is a bit easier to work with. Also, I believe $B^C$ is simply the closure of $A$. That set is always closed. That is how I would go about this problem.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio, thank you!
However, can I not generalise from the conclusions a draw from the closed/open set? 
That is, if my proof holds true for either of them, then it should also hold true for when A is neither closed nor open?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This is my first day of doing Topology (ever) so I'm not quite sure. But I'll make a guess from what I have read on wikipedia so far:
So, f(x) maps values that form the entire set B. This function is continuous at a point, say a, in the set A, if and only if for any neighbourhood in B, there is a neighbourhood in A. Since they both have neighbourhoods, and we know that the function maps entire A to entire B, they must both be open if the function is continuous. Since a neighbourhood means it is an open set? 
Is this what you meant?

Comment: @AnneBauval Hmm, I do not think so to be honest. At least I am not able to see the connection.

Comment: @Julieawl9 That seems like a good idea. Since I haven't done that proof, would it involve showing that a point on the boundary is in both $B^C$ and $B$? Thus making A a closed set and B an open set, since A has to be closed if it has a point on its' boundary?

Comment: If $f(x)=d(x\mathbin;A)$ then $\forall x,y\in\Bbb{R}^n\ d\big(f(x),f(y)\big)\leqslant d(x,y)$ (by use of the triangular inequality), which implies the _continuity_ of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

In (1) In the case that A is closed, the limit point will be contained in the set and $d(x^{'},A)$ will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some issues with the proof:

- As pointed out in Sassatelli Giulio's comment, not every $A$ has to be either opened or closed.
- In the case that $A$ is closed, it is true that there will be a point in $A$ that is closest to $x$, but this needs justification, and seems harder to prove than the target statement.
- In the open case, $\hat d$ is playing many roles and it's not clear if some of these are supposed to be the same point. In particular, if $\hat d$ is chosen before $\epsilon$ then you have two different constraints on $\epsilon$ and it is not clear that those are consistent.
- What is "the ball $C$"? $C_r$ depends on $r$ and you have not specified what $r$ should be. The "this should prove..." might need justification depending on exactly how this is resolved.